# Reopening a fancybox

Tags: asp.net, fancybox

Here's my scenario: I have a page that have a link in the name of someone, when you click on it, it opens a fancybox and you can type a message in a text box. If the user ins't logged in I close the fancybox, and redirect the behind page to my login/register page.

What I need is that after logging in or registering, the user was redirected back to the page with the fancybox open and the text that the user typed before needs to still be there.

Anyone have a suggestion of how doing it? I thought about Sessions to keep the text, but I don't think that's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using cookies for the same?  Save to cookie in case you are redirecting him to login page and load it back when he is redirected back.

Comment: But isn't Session already a cookie? If you have a good read about cookies you could share. It could clarify me, never really used it.

Comment: session data gets saved in the server side. the link can help you to quickly start using cookies http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/244904/Cookies-in-ASP-NET.